# Ruby on Rails: How to migrate changes after adding validation on models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, migrate

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm currently working on models. I have added a new validation to pre created attribute.

This is the validation that I have added.

```
validates_presence_of :services, :message => 'This field is non-editable'
```

Do I have to migrate the changes after adding validation? If yes then how?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records already in your database won't be affected. But it you edit a previous record, you won't be able to store it without passing the validation.

You've 3 options:

- On edit/update, force new field value (default in your case)
- Create a migration to set default value on the column.
- Create a migration to update each row with a correct value (not really a good option in my mind)